# How do you update an image source from a variable state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Essentially, I am trying to change the image source between a pause/play icon inside a button each time the button is clicked. My problem is not so much passing the state into the source as it is having the source change when the state is updated.

```
const playButton = "/images/play-button.svg";
const pauseButton = "/images/pause-button.svg";
```

I have a data source we'll call `data` which is an array with audio files, and I map this to a parallel array containing the audio object, the playstate, and the url to the button, something like:

```
const [audioArray, setAudioArray] = useState([]);
useEffect( () => {

var audioArrayHolder = [];
data.map( item => {
            var audioItem = new Audio(item.audioURL);
            audioArrayHolder.push({
                                   audio: audioItem,
                                   playState: false,
                                   button: playButton
                                 })
});
setAudioArray(audioArrayHolder);
}, [data]);
```

This can now be loaded into a set of components, each with a button that handles the playing of their audio:

```
function handlePausePlay(someIndex) {
     var audioArrayCopy = audioArray;
     var audioArrayObj = audioArray(someIndex);

     if (audioArrayObj.playState) {
        audioArrayObj.audio.pause();
        audioArrayObj.playState = false;
        audioArrayObj.button = playButton;

 } else {
        audioArrayObj.audio.play();
        audioArrayObj.playState = true;
        audioArrayObj.button = pauseButton;
 }

     audioArrayCopy[someIndex] = audioArrayObj;
     setAudioArray(audioArrayCopy);
}

data.map( (item, index) => {

<div>
   <ExampleComponent songName={data.name} songArtists={data.artists}/>

   <button onClick={handlePausePlay(index)}>
      <img src={audioArray[index].button} alt="Pause/Play Button"/>
   </button>
</div>

});
```

This loads all the components fine with a functional pause/play button that simply doesn't change image. Each time the button is pressed, `handlePausePlay` updates the state of `audioArray` at that index, and it changes the `audioArray[index].button` property successfully, but the `src` is already rendered and so the image is stuck as `playButton`, the default.

I have tried making the image a separate component and passing the `src` as a prop, and saving the index into a state const called `currentIndex` with the button press, and passing that into the source (i.e. `<img src={audioArray[currentIndex].button} ... />`) and a whole lot of dumber ideas in between.

This should be a trivial issue but it has honestly confounded me as a newbie for the better part of 2 days. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What could be the content of audioArray[index].button?  "playButton" ?

Comment: yes, at the top of the question it is defined as the url to the image. It is also functional in that the images are successfully displaying the url, just not re-rendering when the .button property is set to pauseButton

Comment: Could you add the code of handlePausePlay to the post?

Comment: Sure, I don't think it's the cleanest way to do it though haha. It does work, in that audio starts/stops, which means the .playState property is being updated (and .button is as well)

Answer (score 0):

i have one solution that might work

create new state loading

```
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
```

then  set Loading to true in handlePausePlay Like this:

```
function handlePausePlay(someIndex) {
selLoading(true)
     var audioArrayCopy = audioArray;
     var audioArrayObj = audioArray(someIndex);

 if (audioArrayObj.playState) {
    audioArrayObj.audio.pause();
    audioArrayObj.playState = false;
    audioArrayObj.button = playButton;

 } else {
        audioArrayObj.audio.play();
        audioArrayObj.playState = true;
        audioArrayObj.button = pauseButton;
 }
     audioArrayCopy[someIndex] = audioArrayObj;
     setAudioArray(audioArrayCopy);

setTimeout(()=>setLoading(false),1000)
    }
```

then with img tag do this:

```
<div>


 <ExampleComponent songName={data.name} songArtists={data.artists}/>

   <button onClick={handlePausePlay(index)}>
      !loading && <img src={audioArray[index].button} alt="Pause/Play Button"/>
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let we see.

I found some things that we need to pay attention to.

First of all:

```
var audioArrayObj = audioArray(someIndex);
```

`audioArray` is not a function is an array, so to access to the value that you need you have to use `[]`

```
var audioArrayObj = audioArray[someIndex];
```

Second, I recommend to use only one array to show your data, not a mix of two array like you are doing at the `return`.

```
data.map( (item, index) => {

<div>
   <ExampleComponent songName={data.name} songArtists={data.artists}/>

   <button onClick={handlePausePlay(index)}>
      <img src={audioArray[index].button} alt="Pause/Play Button"/>
   </button>
</div>

});
```

Inside this code I found your onClick function isn't a arrow function... this will cause an executed on render. Thus, it wouldn't work as you expected.

```
onClick={handlePausePlay(index)}
```

Correct way of use:

```
onClick={()=>handlePausePlay(index)}
```

Finally, I created a snippet with working code.
With only one array to show the data, I take `audioArray` with the `data` values and I mix it on the `useEffect`.
I use spans to simulate the images and I add the altButton text as a variable of each object.
I remove the `new Audio` code only to make the code snippet works correctly.
And at the end of the `handlePausePlay` function I use the `spread operator` to make useState realize that it have a new value.

```
setAudioArray([...audioArrayCopy]);
```

Code snippet:

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState, useEffect} = React;
const playButton = "/images/play-button.svg";
const pauseButton = "/images/pause-button.svg";

const Example = () => {

  const [audioArray, setAudioArray] = useState([{
     playState: false,
     altText: "Play Button",
     button: playButton
  },{
     playState: false,
     altText: "Play Button",
     button: playButton
  },{
     playState: false,
     altText: "Play Button",
     button: playButton
  }
  ]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([{
    name: "Song1", 
    artist: "Artist1"
  },{
    name: "Song2", 
    artist: "Artist2"
  },{
    name: "Song3", 
    artist: "Artist3"
  }]);
  
    useEffect( () => {
      var audioArrayHolder = [];
      data.map( item => {
        audioArrayHolder.push({
                               name: item.name, 
                               artist: item.artist,
                               playState: false,
                               altText: "Play Button",
                               button: playButton
                             })
      });
      setAudioArray(audioArrayHolder);
    }, [data]);
  
  
  const handlePausePlay = (someIndex) => {
       var audioArrayCopy = audioArray;
       var audioArrayObj = audioArray[someIndex];

       if (audioArrayObj.playState) {
          audioArrayObj.playState = false;
          audioArrayObj.altText = "Play Button",
          audioArrayObj.button = playButton;
     } else {
            audioArrayObj.playState = true;
            audioArrayObj.altText = "Pause Button",
            audioArrayObj.button = pauseButton;
     }

       audioArrayCopy[someIndex] = audioArrayObj;
       setAudioArray([...audioArrayCopy]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {audioArray.map( (item, index) => {
      return <div>
         <span> Playing {item.name} - ({item.artist}) </span>

         <button onClick={()=>handlePausePlay(index)}>
            {/*<img src={item.button} alt="Pause/Play Button"/>*/}
            <span> src={item.button} alt={item.altText}</span>
         </button>
      </div>
      })}
    </div>
  );
};




// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example title="Example using Hooks:" />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Wow this worked! I think the combination of the spread operator use and combining the arrays did it. I don't know why I didn't think of using one array, I guess you after writing it over so many times I got tunnel vision.
The span change didn't work out as "playButton" and "pauseButton" are just strings, so it was displaying a text block in the button, but implementing as an image re-renders just fine. Added back in the .play() and it's perfect.
Sorry about making you bugfix the errors too, I manually wrote out the code for the question to simplify the problem and I guess I made some typos.

Comment: I am glad it help you! Greetings